# How to change screen orientation in VirtualBox (Windows XP Guest OS) from Landscape to Portrait

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox

I want to change the screen orientation in Windows XP running as Guest OS from VirtualBox from default(Landscape) to portrait. In my host OS, where it have access to graphics drivers etc, I see option to rotate the screen to 4 different angles i.e. 0, 90, 180, 270. But this option isn't visible in Graphics Driver properties under Guest OS(Windows XP). Could any one suggest, how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this issue myself using a Windows 7 guest.  There is no orientation option available there either.  However, I figured a workaround under Windows 7 that you might be able to use also (I don't have an XP guest handy, sorry):

Control Panel -> Display -> Screen Resolution -> Advanced Settings (link button) -> List All Modes (button)

From the list, I manually chose the portrait orientation resolution I know is used for my setup.

For example, I have two 1920x1080 screens.  One is landscape and one is portrait.  For my portrait screen, I manually chose its resolution as 1080x1920 instead.  This solved my issue.

Dragging across them is a little buggy sometimes, though.

Think I might need to grab a multiple monitor management program like DisplyFusion or Ultramon to help with this a little.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

On a Linux host, I set the resolution manually with:
`VBoxManage setextradata "<vm-name>" "CustomVideoMode1" "1200x1920x32"`